# Amcharts Candle-Stick balloon text is showing timestamps in wrong format

Tags: javascript, amcharts, boxplot, candlestick-chart

I am using amcharts to draw the Candle-stick pattern chart. The charts is rendering well but the balloon shows the timestamps in some other format.

[image]

[image]

Actually, The values are in **"HH:MM:SS"** format but the balloon is showing in some different format. Where as it's showing correctly only in 'Mid:' (i.e. **14:23:49**).

Here is my code :

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "titles": [{
    "text": "amCharts Box Plot Example",
    "size": 15
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "type": "candlestick",
    "balloonText": "High: [[high]]\n Open: [[open]]\n Mid: [[mid]]\n Close: [[close]]\nLow: [[low]]",
    "highField": "high",
    "openField": "open",
    "closeField": "close",
    "valueField": "close",
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillColors": "#ffffff",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "columnWidth": 0.4
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.2,
    "valueField": "high",
    "openField": "high",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.2,
    "valueField": "low",
    "openField": "low",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.4,
    "valueField": "mid",
    "openField": "mid",
    "lineColor": "orange",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }
"chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "exp",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "title": "Experiment No.",
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 10,
    "axisAlpha": 0.7,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  },

   "dataDateFormat": "HH:NN:SS",
                        //"dataProvider": chartData,
                        "valueAxes": [{
                                "id": "v1",
                                "position": "left",
                                "title": "Time of the Day",
                                "type": "date",
                               // "minimumDate": minDateStr,
                               // "maximumDate": maxDateStr,
                                "markPeriodChange": false,
                                "autoGridCount": false,
                                "gridCount": 7,
                                "minPeriod": "ss",
                            }

                        ],
```

and below is the dataProvider:

```
 "dataProvider": [{
    "exp": 1,
    "high": "07:54:00",
    "open": "07:45:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close":"04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 2,
    "high": "09:54:00",
    "open": "08:10:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close":"04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 3,
   "high": "17:54:00",
    "open": "15:20:00",
    "mid": "14:23:49",
    "close":"12:48:37",
    "low": "11:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 4,
   "high": "11:54:00",
    "open": "08:10:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close":"04:48:37",
    "low": "02:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 5,
   "high": "15:54:00",
    "open": "12:50:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close":"04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }]
```

Not sure why it's not showing in given format for all. Do I need to format them explicitly? Any suggestions would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Normally you'd set [`dateFormat`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amgraph/#dateFormat_property) in your graph object to the desired output format (`HH:NN:SS` in this case) and it will work, however it doesn't seem to impact values other than `[[open]]` and `[[value]]`. Your only option in this case is to use a [`balloonFunction`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amgraph/#balloonFunction_property) and format them by hand.

Here's a basic demo that just returns the direct string values from your data without reformatting:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "type": "serial",
  "theme": "light",
  "titles": [{
    "text": "amCharts Box Plot Example",
    "size": 15
  }],
  "graphs": [{
    "type": "candlestick",
    "balloonText": "High: [[high]]\n Open: [[open]]\n Mid: [[mid]]\n Close: [[close]]\nLow: [[low]]",
    "highField": "high",
    "balloonFunction": function(graphDataItem) {
      var dataItem = graphDataItem.dataContext;
      return "High: " + dataItem.high + "<br>Open: " + dataItem.open + "<br>Mid: " + dataItem.mid + "<br>Close: " + dataItem.close + "<br>Low: " + dataItem.low
    },
    //"dateFormat": "HH:NN:SS", //does not work with all fields
    "openField": "open",
    "closeField": "close",
    "valueField": "close",
    "lowField": "low",
    "fillColors": "#ffffff",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "fillAlphas": 0.9,
    "columnWidth": 0.4
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.2,
    "valueField": "high",
    "openField": "high",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.2,
    "valueField": "low",
    "openField": "low",
    "lineColor": "blue",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }, {
    "type": "column",
    "columnWidth": 0.4,
    "valueField": "mid",
    "openField": "mid",
    "lineColor": "orange",
    "lineThickness": 3,
    "showBalloon": false,
    "clustered": false
  }],
  "chartCursor": {
    "valueLineEnabled": true,
    "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true
  },
  "categoryField": "exp",
  "categoryAxis": {
    "title": "Experiment No.",
    "gridPosition": "start",
    "tickPosition": "start",
    "tickLength": 10,
    "axisAlpha": 0.7,
    "gridAlpha": 0
  },

  "dataDateFormat": "HH:NN:SS",
  "dataProvider": [{
    "exp": 1,
    "high": "07:54:00",
    "open": "07:45:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close": "04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 2,
    "high": "09:54:00",
    "open": "08:10:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close": "04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 3,
    "high": "17:54:00",
    "open": "15:20:00",
    "mid": "14:23:49",
    "close": "12:48:37",
    "low": "11:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 4,
    "high": "11:54:00",
    "open": "08:10:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close": "04:48:37",
    "low": "02:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }, {
    "exp": 5,
    "high": "15:54:00",
    "open": "12:50:00",
    "mid": "05:23:49",
    "close": "04:48:37",
    "low": "03:44:57",
    "interimSLA": "12:30:00",
    "targetedSLA": "08:00:00",
  }],
  "valueAxes": [{
      "id": "v1",
      "position": "left",
      "title": "Time of the Day",
      "type": "date",
      // "minimumDate": minDateStr,
      // "maximumDate": maxDateStr,
      "markPeriodChange": false,
      "autoGridCount": false,
      "gridCount": 7,
      "minPeriod": "ss"
    }

  ],
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
}

#chartdiv {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```